# Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1237

Tags: winforms, exe

I have a Winforms application that runs fine on my computer when I open the exe file, but when I asked someone else to run it on their computer (exact same type of laptop) it didn't work. I sent them the entire the entire netcoreapp3.1 file, which has all of the dependency files in it, and they weren't able to run it from there. This was the Event Viewer log:

```
Faulting application name: shell-launcher.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5f8de6f1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1237, time stamp: 0x71e81044
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000043b29
Faulting process id: 0x3d94
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6e84259496fb6
Faulting application path: C:\Users\11031122\Downloads\ShellLauncher\ShellLauncher\shell-launcher.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 731a8bf6-28be-479e-b3a6-d915e3fa1873
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've read some posts that suggest exception handling, but I'm not sure which file/where to put the exceptions, and in general, why would it work on my computer fine if that was the case?

Comment: I had the same error right now... I was simply missing a dependency (a dll) on the target PC. Be sure to provide all dll's in the bin folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found that after changing version of my dependent package from  Nuget packages everything worked smoothly. Just before this exception there would be another error which can be traced from Event Manager or call trace.